# MVC3 telerik gird jquery check if grid has rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I have a button on my page when it's clicked I want to check if my grid has rows

```
 function CheckBusinessLicense() {
            var data = $('#License').data('tGrid');            
            var tr = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(tr);
        }
```

but these return a string of information. How can I find if my grid have data or rows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago.  This is what I came up with.

```
var grid = $("#License").data("tGrid");
if (grid.data.length != 0)
    alert(grid.data.length);
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Is giving a error" Unable to get value of the property 'length'

Comment: Strange...  When are you trying to check the number of rows?  It may have to do something with that.  When I did it, I ended up checking it during the OnDataBound event for the grid.

Comment: I'm checking after the grid is bound. My function belongs to a save button..trying to check if grid has data before save

Comment: Weirdness. I moved my piece into the save of a button and I was able to get back the proper result. Can you maybe post more so I can see what is up with it?

Edit:  Maybe do this: alert(grid.data);
This should give you [Object object], ... etc.  Just checking to see if it recognizes the grid or not.  Thanks.

Comment: var grid = $('#License').data('tGrid');
            rows = $(grid.element).find(".t-no-data");
           
            alert(rows.length);

Comment: That works too.  Weird it couldn't be found using what I had.  Glad you found it at the very least.